# AsNoTracking on context properties, query or ChangeTracker?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I noticed that it is possible to disable tracking in three different ways:

- via `AsNoTracking` on context properties
- via `AsNoTracking` on the final query before executing it
- via `context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior`

Is there any difference between these three approaches if I want to disable tracking for everything?

If I previously used `AsNoTracking` after each context property and now I replace it with only a single call on the final query (or disable it via the `ChangeTracker`) will it have the same effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`AsNoTracking`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asnotracking?view=efcore-2.1) and [`AsTracking`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.astracking?view=efcore-2.1) are extension methods of `IQueryable<T>`, thus are associated with the state of the query and not a specific entity (the fact that they are available at `DbSet<T>` level is just because it implements `IQueryable<T>`) - note the word **all** inside the method descriptions:

**AsNoTracking**

> Returns a new query where the change tracker will not track any of the entities that are returned.

**AsTracking**

> Returns a new query where the change tracker will keep track of changes for all entities that are returned.

And both say:

> The default tracking behavior for queries can be controlled by [QueryTrackingBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.querytrackingbehavior?view=efcore-2.1).

In other words, if the query returns entities and there is no `AsNoTracking` or `AsTracking` calls *anywhere* in the query expression tree, the query uses the value of the `ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior`.

So the answer to your question is yes, you can achieve the same effect with a single call on the final query or via `ChangeTracker`.

There is one thing to note though, which is not explained in the documentation. If the query expression tree contains more than one `AsNoTracking` / `AsTracking` calls, the *last* call takes precedence. Which means that by adding `AsNoTracking` or if you add `AsTracking` to the final query will control it's behavior regardless of the any inner tracking behavior calls or `ChangeTracker` property.

Answer (score 4):

`AsNoTracking` works for individual query level

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    var data = context.Entity
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
}
```

You can also change the default tracking behavior at the context instance level:

If you want to do this at context instance level, you can do like this, unlike EF 6 (AsNoTracking() is mandatory each time you make query):

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    var data = context.Entity.ToList();
}
```