# Where to place AsNoTracking on a Entity Framework query?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following Entity Framework Core 2.2 query:

```
IQueryable<Job> jobs = _context.Jobs.AsNoTracking();

jobs = jobs.Where(x => x.Active);

jobs.Skip(offset).Take(limit);

var result = jobs
  .Select(x => new {
    Id = x.Id,
    Country = new {
      Code = x.Country.Code,
      Name = x.Country.Name
    },
    JobTypes = _context.JobTypes.Select(x => x.Name),
    Created = x.Created,
    Skills = x.JobSkills.Select(y => new {
      Id = y.Skill.Id,
      Name = y.Skill.Name
    })
  });

return await result.ToListAsync();
```

I am using AsNoTracking() to make the query faster. The question is:

Is there a specific place where to place AsNoTracking()?

Should I place it before ToListAsync instead of in the beginning?

Comment: It doesn't matter - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52400940/asnotracking-on-context-properties-query-or-changetracker/52405365#52405365

Comment: I updated my answer with the following: JobTypes = _context.JobTypes.Select(x => x.Name), as a child query. Do I need to add AsNoTracking() after context.JobTypes or the one in _context.Jobs is enough? I maybe I add the AsNoTracking before the ToListAsync and this one will take care of both?

Comment: No, you don't need it - the one at the beginning is enough. As I wrote in the linked answer, tracking is a property of the whole query, not the `DbSet`. And btw, since your query is using projection, it doesn't need `AsNoTracking` at all - tracking is in effect only for queries which return entities.

Comment: Thank you for the information. If you add you text as an answer I will mark it as the answer.